# jQuery on() does not fire on a dynamically generated / clicked radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page on which I dynamically generate a bunch of radio buttons with id's like "r_op_1" / "r_op_2" etc.

Within my `document.ready` jQuery block I have

```
$('input:radio[id^="r_op_"]').on("click", function (e) {
 alert("I'm here");   
 ....  
 });
```

The function never executes. The same block worked in the older versions of jQuery (1.8x) but as I upgraded jQuery I've had to use the `on()` function.

What am I missing? Is my selector wrong or am I supposed to use the `on()` in some other way?

I am clueless at this point - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try somethign like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio[id^="r_op_"]', function(event) {
    alert("I'm here");  
});
```

Answer (score -2):

yea i think that `on()` function does not support the dynamic DOM elements  try to use `live()` instead but i think it is deprecated